# Lightweight C# IDE with code completion feature

Tags: c#, ide

I have little amount of job to do in C#, and I'd like to avoid buying&installing Visual Studio for it.

Are there some lightweight IDE-s for C#? I think, the most important feature for me would be code completion.

Thanks in advance! Vitaly.

Comment: VS Express might be a good thing for you, its free! :) http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I use the express version of Visual Studio.
It does all the small stuff.

I think that Microsoft brought it in because they were losing the home and student developers.

Comment: I didn't know that VS has free express edition. Thank you, it perfectly fits my needs.

Comment: If you are using windows 8 then the 2013 is perfect , but if you are using windows 7 or earlier then download 2010